# Does Left Cross Punch exist for Orthodox stance fighters?

Tags: technique, mixed-martial-arts, boxing, muay-thai

Being an orthodox stance fighter, there is a "right cross" that counteracts an opponent left jab.

Does a "left cross" also exist for orthodox fighters? It would seem to counteract an opponent's right punch straight. I tested, and it works sometimes in sparring. However I never read about it.

*Only seen it for southpaw stance fighters obviously.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgiFPvOI8rM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3343mBxM8E

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean here.  People move around in a match.  What is the difference between a 'left jab' and a 'left cross'?  Obviously you can move from orthodox to southpaw stance in a match if you really want to.  Otherwise you can position yourself so your left jab 'crosses' the opponent's right arm... but why would you?